# Store meta-data in shared library so it is accessible without loading the whole library

Tags: shared-libraries, c++14, metadata

I want to make my program extensible.
The user should be able to decide if an extension should be loaded or not. To help the user decide I'd like to embed meta-data like a short description into the shared object.

My question is: **How do I make the meta-data easily accessible without having to load the entire object?** Is there a C++ way of placing data in a specific location?

Furthermore I'd like this to be as platform-independant as possible.
I want to `fopen` the file then `fseek` to a certain position and find my meta-data there.
I thought about a string that has a specific start which I could search for, but this seems like a elementary school solution.